# If limit of squared sequence it zero is it true to say that the limit of the sequence is zero?

Tags: calculus

I want to make sure I understand it right. If $lim_{n\to \infty} (a_{n})^2 = 0$, is it sure to say that $lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n} = 0$. If not how to prove/disprove it. I though its zero because:

$$
lim_{n\to \infty} (a_{n})^2 = lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n} \cdot  lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n} = 0\cdot 0 = 0
$$

Comment: do you mean series or sequence?

Comment: @BorKari I meant sequence (sorry, will edit)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt x$, it is continuous, if $b_n>0, lim_nb_n=b, lim_nf(b_n)=f(b)$ take $b_n=a_n^2$, $f(b_n)=|a_n|$ and $lim_n|a_n|=0$ is equivalent to $lim_na_n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach does not work, because

$$\lim (a_n\cdot a_n) =\lim (a_n)\cdot \lim (a_n)$$

is only true if $\lim a_n$ exists. Also, you are not making a conclusion about $a_n$ at all.

To properly show this, let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|a_n^2|<\epsilon^2$

Comment: how $N$ should look like?

Comment: $N$ is a guaranteed "cutoff" for all $n$ for which $|a_n^2|<\epsilon^2$. It does not have a specific representation.